# Selenium wait for page load python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently attempting to submit a form using selenium driver through python 2.7.12 and then retrieving the loaded page. The code i currently does not seem to wait for the page load this is the code i have:

```
while False:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_lblStockName") #oldpage id
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        continue

print ("Page is ready!")
f = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')
print (soup)
```

The code above just prints the html of the page before the search. I'm unsure whether my while loop is working.

I have attempted another method using the timeout function but the error comes up as

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage'
```

Also I have read that using timeout is not especially reliable either, so I would like to avoid this method unless it's the only option.

Comment: Can you share page url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check your code driver.manage() is being called remove the function call look for the alternative in python bindings (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

driver.manage(). is in Java Bindings of Selenium not in Python Bindings.

Comment: so what's the one we can use in python??

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(int secs)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still looking for the Python solution:

```
set_page_load_timeout(*time in seconds*)
```

e.g.

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)     #waits for a page to load within 20 seconds before Selenium throws out Timeout exception
```